# 'Swap line' function in sublime text greyed out

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

I've seen a few people having problems with getting the swap line keyboard shortcuts to work online, but they all seem to have had the option available in the edit menu. For some reason I can't figure out, the swap line options are both greyed out in the Sublime->edit->line menu. What could be causing this?

[image: The menu in question]

Comment: The implementation of these commands is in `Defaults/swap_line.py` and the code there doesn't have anything that would selectively disable the command. The only other reason I can think of for the commands being disabled is them being missing. I would check that you don't have an override for anything in the `Default` package.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How can I open/check these?

Comment: You can select `Preferences > Browse Packages...` from the menu. In the window that pops up, check to see if there is a folder named `Default` in there. If there is, moving it away and restarting sublime may help.

Comment: Amazing, this fixed it, thank you.

In case anyone else has the same problem: the Default folder wasn't initially there, but I created it and made a .py file called swap_line.py myself, restarted, deleted the folder, and restarted again, and now it's working